# Tunnel Ethernet Packets over SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ethernet, ssh-tunnel

I have two machines. My laptop and a machine in the local intranet. This machine has next to the network device (for the intranet) a second network card. I want to send raw ethernet frames out of this second device.

How can I tunnel from my local laptop onto this server and forward those packets on the right device?

Comment: Do you really want to tunnel the connection over ssh, or are you just trying to use the "machine" as a router?

Answer (score 1):

[EoIP](http://dalemonk.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/extend-your-lan-between-sites-using-an-ethernet-over-ip-eoip-bridge-and-pptp/) would be on of the simplest thing to use, since you don't have to worry about encrypting the tunnel between the two systems. But you can also use [veth](https://code.google.com/p/veth/), or [tunnel over ssh](http://www.khanh.net/blog/archives/51-using-openSSH-as-a-layer-2-ethernet-bridge-VPN.html), but with the ssh solution you'll need openssh 4.3+ .

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to tunnel Ethernet (layer 2) over SSH over TCP (layer 3).  Since TCP tries hard to guarantee lossless transmission, you could have multiple layers all trying to retransmit dropped packets.

Use a proper tunnelling technology, such as OpenVPN, L2TP, or IPSec.

Comment: No, that's not really what's happenning. There's lots of tunnelling technologies that use TCP over TCP. And ssh tunnelling has been around for a very long time. The advantages of a specifically designed VPN protocol are all to do with session management.

Comment: @symcbean yes lots of tools do tcp in tcp.  There are well kmown problems with it.  http://sites.inka.de/~W1011/devel/tcp-tcp.html. TCP can wotk but it isn't ideal.